# Record button disabled in Xcode UI Test Target

Tags: ios, xcode, ui-testing

I know similar questions have been posted, but from my investigating, there has not been a solution posted, at least not one that works. I have successfully run UI tests only from sample projects in both Swift and Obj-C.

I am trying (unsuccessfully) to integrate UI tests into an existing Xcode Obj-C project, which seems to be another issue altogether. Here are the steps I have taken:

1. Created a new UI Test target within my project
2. Ensured that 'Enable Testability' has been set to YES for the target I am testing
3. Cleaned, cleaned build folder, rebuilt the app, restarted Xcode and everything else I could think of.

When I do this, the test target is available but the record button is greyed out (disabled) and there are no play buttons in the gutter to execute the tests. There is nothing visual about the test class that would indicate that it is a test class. When I place my cursor in the test method, the record button remains disabled.

Is there anything I've left out? Anything else to check that might be preventing UI tests?

Comment: when you select the uitest file (in the project navigator on the left), do you see that it indeed has the target membership of your UITest target (in the Utilities pane on the right that lets you check/uncheck the Target Membership) ?

Comment: Wow that worked, how annoying is that! Checking and unchecking the membership of the target works : / Please fix that @Apple

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you are in the correct XCTestCase subclass file.

After researching for a time, I found that I was all the time in a extension file (I'm been ordering the flows in extension files). So when I opened the main XCTestCase subclass file (like "YourAppUItests") the record test button has been enabled.

Answer (score 30):

1. Record button only gets enabled within a function body.
2. The function name must start with `test`. Like `testExample()`.
3. After changing the name of the function wait for a few seconds for the run icon to appear in the gutter.

Now the record button should appear.

Comment: Great Man!! Its works for me. just need to append "test" word

Comment: Problem with the disabled button of record UITest solved with the word "test", it looking like a joke but it is work.

Comment: yes, prefix with "test". This because you can also implement some fonctions that are not tests, e.g. for code factorisation.

Answer (score 12):

I followed all the tips listed here, and the only thing that fixed it was **restarting Xcode**.

Comment: Xcode 15.2. This helps me.

Answer (score 3):

1. Click on 6th button from top of the left pane - *Show the test navigator*
2. Right click on the UI tests, then click on "Enable ... "

Then you can record.

Comment: Mine was enabled. Disabled and enabled again which fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you can build for the test target successfully.

Go to **Product > Test**, and make sure the UI Testing test case is run (it is fine if the test case is empty). You should also see the test cases under Test Navigator, or in the app target scheme.

Comment: That was it. Simply clicking the play button next to the test name doesn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have at least one test function in your ui test class. For example- func testExample(){}. Then you'll be able to record in that function as you can only run functions as tests if they have test as prefix.

Answer (score 1):

I realized you had to have your cursor inside the test function you want to record for. I simply clicked inside the test function and the record button got enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure you select the UI test scheme, which was the problem in my case:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your project has a test plan (`.xctestplan`) then make sure that the new test is enabled. Till then the record button will be disabled. This often happens when you add a new **UI Test Case Class**. Or when you add new test to existing class which has some of the tests disabled.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't see the rhombuses against the function definition that allows you to run the specific test in your editor, that means something is wrong with Xcode and you should try to reopen it. Helped me. Until you don't see the rhombuses the record button is disabled.

Comment: Restart was already among the answers, rhombus is a side effect.

Answer (score -1):

1. create function in yourfileUITests.swift

[image]

2. running program by TEST

[image]

3. your function can record UI Testing, button already enable

[image]